# Problem with uploading file to firebase storage through .Net Maui

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, maui

I'm doing a project where we need to register a student with its picture. The student object goes to 'realtime database' without problem but the part where I send the picture never happens. As in I click on the register button and nothing happens, no error, nothing. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Register : ContentPage
{
    private bool imagenSeleccionada= false;
    FirebaseClient client = new FirebaseClient("route.firebasedatabase.app/");
    private string rutaStorage = "route";
    private Stream stream;
    private string token = String.Empty;

    public Register()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            await ObtenerToken();
        }
    }

    public async void OnChoosePhotoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Por favor elige una foto"
            });

            if (result != null)
            {
                stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                profileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                imagenSeleccionada = true;
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public async void OnRegisterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nombreEntry.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contraseñaEntry.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reescribeContraseñaEntry.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(centroDocenteEntry.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(profesorSeguimientoEntry.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(centroTrabajoEntry.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tutorTrabajoEntry.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cicloFormativoEntry.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(gradoEntry.Text) &&
                imagenSeleccionada)
            {
                if (contraseñaEntry.Text.Equals(reescribeContraseñaEntry.Text))
                {

                        var storageImageTask = new FirebaseStorage(rutaStorage, new FirebaseStorageOptions
                        {
                            AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(token),
                            ThrowOnCancel = true
                        })
                        .Child("fotos-perfil")
                        .Child(nombreEntry.Text)
                        .PutAsync(stream);

                        var rutaImage = await storageImageTask; /*problem is here, the storageImageTask is not null but rutaImage is and the code won't go any further*/

                        await client.Child("Alumno").PostAsync(new Alumno
                        {
                            Nombre = nombreEntry.Text,
                            Contraseña = Encrypt.GetSha256(contraseñaEntry.Text),
                            CentroDocente = centroDocenteEntry.Text,
                            ProfesorSeguimiento = profesorSeguimientoEntry.Text,
                            CentroTrabajo = centroTrabajoEntry.Text,
                            TutorTrabajo = tutorTrabajoEntry.Text,
                            CicloFormativo = cicloFormativoEntry.Text,
                            Grado = gradoEntry.Text,
                            FotoPath = rutaImage
                        });
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Week());
                }
                else
                {
                    await this.DisplayAlert("Error", "Te has equivocado al reescribir la contraseña", "Ok");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await this.DisplayAlert("Error", "Rellene todos los campos por favor", "Ok");
            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public async Task ObtenerToken()
    {
        try
        {
            string authDomain = "something.firebaseapp.com";
            string apiKey = "apikey";
            string email = "something@gmail.com";
            string password = "123456";

            var client = new FirebaseAuthClient(new FirebaseAuthConfig()
            {
                ApiKey = apiKey,
                AuthDomain = authDomain,
                Providers = new FirebaseAuthProvider[]
                {
                    new EmailProvider()
                }
            });
            var credenciales = await client.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
            token = await credenciales.User.GetIdTokenAsync();
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the firebase storage rules to `allow read, write: if request.auth==null;` and then to `allow read, write;` to see if it was a problem with my token (I also took out the code related to the token) but I keep on getting the same problem.

Comment: What is the Firebase package you use?

Comment: I'm using Firebase.Auth.Providers, Firebase.Auth, Firebase.Database, Firebase.Database.Query and Firebase.Storage;

Comment: Well, you can also reach the official doc: [Display pop-ups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups?view=net-maui-8.0) to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. First off I had a problem with my `try-catch` clause the `Console.WriteLine` didn't do its job.

So I replaced it by `this.DisplayAlert` and then the real problem was that the stream with the picture was closed before it made to the upload method (`ObjectDisposedException`: Cannot access a closed Stream.) so here is my new code:

```
public async void OnChoosePhotoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
    var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
    {
        Title = "Por favor elige una foto"
    });

    if (result != null)
    {
        newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, result.FileName);
        using (var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
            await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
        profileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(newFile);
        imagenSeleccionada = true;
    }
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    await this.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
}
}

public async void OnRegisterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
try
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nombreEntry.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contraseñaEntry.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reescribeContraseñaEntry.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(centroDocenteEntry.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(profesorSeguimientoEntry.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(centroTrabajoEntry.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tutorTrabajoEntry.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cicloFormativoEntry.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(gradoEntry.Text) &&
        imagenSeleccionada)
    {
        if (contraseñaEntry.Text.Equals(reescribeContraseñaEntry.Text))
        {
            using (var uploadStream = File.OpenRead(newFile))
            {
                var storageImageTask = new FirebaseStorage(rutaStorage, new FirebaseStorageOptions
                {
                    AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(token),
                    ThrowOnCancel = true
                })
                .Child("fotos-perfil")
                .Child(nombreEntry.Text)
                .PutAsync(uploadStream);

                var rutaImage = await storageImageTask;

                await client.Child("Alumno").PostAsync(new Alumno
                {
                    Nombre = nombreEntry.Text,
                    Contraseña = Encrypt.GetSha256(contraseñaEntry.Text),
                    CentroDocente = centroDocenteEntry.Text,
                    ProfesorSeguimiento = profesorSeguimientoEntry.Text,
                    CentroTrabajo = centroTrabajoEntry.Text,
                    TutorTrabajo = tutorTrabajoEntry.Text,
                    CicloFormativo = cicloFormativoEntry.Text,
                    Grado = gradoEntry.Text,
                    FotoPath = rutaImage
                });
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Week());
        }
        }
        else
        {
            await this.DisplayAlert("Error", "Te has equivocado al reescribir la contraseña", "Ok");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await this.DisplayAlert("Error", "Rellene todos los campos por favor", "Ok");
    }
}catch (Exception ex)
{
    await this.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
}
```

}